# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with saving entity to postgres // simple repository extending jpaRepository,
service which has dependency to repository and controller having dependency to service
When I send body in json from postman, Application crashes and writes : **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
@Service
public class EmployeeService{
 public void save(Employee employee){
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }}

@RestController
public class EmployeeController{
@PostMapping("/employees")
    public void addEmployee(@RequestBody() Employee employee) {
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
}
@Entity
class Employee
employeeId;
firstName;
lastName;
departmentId;
jobTitle;

sample json in postman
{
        "employeeId": 8,
        "firstName": "johny",
        "lastName": "walker",
        "departmentId": 3,
        "jobTitle": "DEV"
    }
```

From where that "with" come from ?
I don't use any query with "with"
What do do to save entity to database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how does the full SQL statement look like? Do you have an attribute in the entity with the name "with"?

Comment: " I don't use any query with "with" ", well the database server just received one... Please check your logfiles, also the database server log files, to find this query.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  :  I dont write my own sql statement, JPA repository provides basic methods for crud operations, and when it comes to save employee to database by using employee body json in postman, upper exception is thrown

Comment: 2022-08-07 16:06:28.908  WARN 16756 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
2022-08-07 16:06:43.924 ERROR 16756 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure   : could not read a hi value

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"
  Position: 51

Comment: Can you please turn SQL logging on and check the generated sql

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found the answer :
I had not correct properties , just make 1 change and everything is ok :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```